# Unable to add path for image in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I was just working on my PHP website and I need database for that, so I was trying to insert image path to phpMyAdmin.

But I am unable to add path because I don't know the exact syntax for image path and also when I am trying to insert image path.

I can't see empty column instead of that. I am watching something like binary and choose file, as you can see in image.

[image]

Comment: phpMyAdmin asks you to choose a file when trying to update a `blob` or `longblob` column.  This is **not** asking for a path to be store, but to physically select the file you wish to upload and store that files contents in that field.

Comment: *i did try that also ,but wen i run it i got this .* * ���ExifII*��Ducky<���+http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/ ��Adobed����      ������ !1AQ"a2q��B�R#�b��r3$���C�S%�4D�c��T!1AQ"a2�q����#��BR�b* * and it fills my full webpage*

Comment: Please post your php code you are using to render your page. `blob` fields are special fields and should not be echo'd out directly when storing binary data.

Comment: You should probable change that blob field to VARCHAR if you just want to store a reference to an URL

Comment: @kraang i am not using any code for inserting image ,i want to add many images so i am adding it by directly giving path to image in phpmyadmin

Comment: @niloVelez ok i will try to change blob,n see what happens

Comment: @NiloVelez i chnaged blob to varchar now its  not showing me in binary but it showing the path of image rather than image,so plz somebody help m and tell me the syntax of path or any example.

Comment: Never load files directly to your database. Store them somewhere and then save the path in DB

Comment: @vrajesh: regarding your edit, if you see requests for urgency, or other fluff, you can remove them entirely rather than tidying them up. Much quicker, and someone else will probably do it after you anyway!

Comment: @Yuri  yess i have saved all images into the same folder where i have saved all php files of site and database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its good to save files / images in folders and just save their name in database.

```
<input type="file" name="photo">


$tmpFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$newFile = $_FILES['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmpFile, '/images/'.$newFile);

$query = "update users set photo = '$newFile' where id = '$userId'";
```

Here I assume that we are going to upload profile photo of users and saving file in images folder. Also, updating file name in database record.

Comment: i have tried by saving their  name on database ...bt still not getting image

Comment: Can you update your code or do email at naveed.ramzan@gmail.com